# Is there a way to construct a security group with all IPv4 and IPv6 egress traffic allowed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I want to connect to an IPv6-only service from a Fargate service, that already connects to IPv4 services.

Ideally, the default security group would include an egress rule for `::/0`, like it does for `0.0.0.0/0`.

I first tried to add it using a `connections`, which did not add the rule to the template.

```js
service.connections.allowTo(Peer.anyIpv6(), Port.allTraffic());
```

Then I tried to construct a security group directly.

```js
const securityGroup = new SecurityGroup(this, 'SecurityGroup', { vpc })
securityGroup.addEgressRule(Peer.anyIpv6(), Port.allTraffic());
```

This gives the warning, and does not add the rule to the template.

> Ignoring Egress rule since 'allowAllOutbound' is set to true; To add customize rules, set allowAllOutbound=false on the SecurityGroup

Finally I tried to construct a security group with `allowAllOutbound=false`, like the warning suggests.

```js
const securityGroup = new SecurityGroup(this, 'SecurityGroup', { vpc, allowAllOutbound: false })
securityGroup.addEgressRule(Peer.anyIpv4(), Port.allTraffic());
securityGroup.addEgressRule(Peer.anyIpv6(), Port.allTraffic());
```

This fails to synth with with the error message:

> Cannot add an "all traffic" egress rule in this way; set allowAllOutbound=true on the SecurityGroup instead.

The comment in the code suggests this was a 'for now' solution, but not ideal. https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/b2bba775282a7b031ae34de6bef838558410cb67/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-ec2/lib/security-group.ts#L530-L535

---

Environment: aws-cdk 2.10.0 (build e5b301f), Typescript 4.5.5, NodeJS v14.18.1

Comment: There may be an argument that you should not do this in the first place. Security group rules are stateful https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html#VPCSecurityGroups - " to allowed inbound traffic are allowed to leave the instance, regardless of the outbound rules." - so what you do does not make sense for any reasonable service.

Comment: @petrch I'm enabling the outbound rule to allow the service to initiate outbound requests to IPv6 hosts (their responses are covered by the statefulness of the SG rule).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the current limitations of CDK the only options I see is using one of the escape hatches (that is, until this bug is fixed):

1. Use the Cfn (L1) construct for security groups (or maybe just the security group egress rule for ipv6) and do it like you would in regular cloudformation (probably the best option)
2. Use a property override and add the `"SecurityGroupEgress" : [ ipv6EgressRule, ipv4EgressRule ]` key-value pair to the underlying Cfn resource.

More info on escape hatches: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cfn_layer.html

Answer (score 0):

From a gitlab issue [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/7094#issuecomment-1067263518)

```
const sg = new SecurityGroup(this, 'SG', {
  vpc: Vpc.fromLookup(this, 'TestVpc', { vpcName: 'TestVpc'}),
  // allowAllOutbound: false
});

const cfnSg = sg.node.defaultChild as CfnSecurityGroup;

cfnSg.addPropertyOverride('SecurityGroupEgress', 
[ 
  {
    "CidrIpv6": "::/0",
    "Description": "from ::/0:ALL TRAFFIC",
    "IpProtocol": "-1"
  },
  {
    "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0",
    "Description": "Allow all outbound traffic by default",
    "IpProtocol": "-1"
  }
]);
```